# Can SVN (on eclipse or not) consider \r and \n as white spaces?

Tags: eclipse, svn, whitespace

So the issue is eclipse thinks that this line:

```
if (true) 
{
    return;
}
```

is diferent from this one:

```
if (true) {return;}
```

This makes a file with no actual changes have hundreds of changes and makes it hard to find what really changed, if we are looking for something specific.

I can tell eclipse\svn to ignore white spaces, why arent \r and \n considered white spaces? And why isn't there an option for that?

Answer (score 0):

Classic `diff` compares file contents [line by line](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html), behavior that's been inherited/mimicked by RCS, CVS, SVN, and git. Also, for some languages, separating a line *does* change behavior.